# Who initializes semaphores?

Tags: c, posix

So, the problem is: I'm writing a "chat simulator" for my university project. Not getting into too much detail, the client can be run multiple times, and all the instances use the same segment of shared memory guarded by a semaphore (among other things).

The clients enter and exit the system at unknown times. When the first client enters the system, it should create a semaphore, use the shared memory and release. If any other client enters the system, however, it has to wait on the semaphore before acquiring a shared memory access.

Now, I feel like I'm missing something obvious - how do I initialize the semaphore? If I use `semget(42, 1, IPC_CREAT)`, the resulting semaphore will most likely be 0 - but I can't raise it to initialize it, since the 0 might mean that there's a process already in the critical section. In other words, I have no idea whether I've just created the semaphore with default value 0, or if there's a process waiting on the semaphore.

In pseudocode:

```
if(semaphore_not_exists(42))
{
    create_sem;
    raise_sem;
}
else
{
    get_sem_handle;
}
wait_on_sem;
critical_section;
release_sem;
```

So, how do I make sure that the semaphore has not yet been created by another process, so that it's safe to initialize it? If I use `IPC_EXCL`, the request will fail, but I don't know what I should do next.

Comment: i think all the users of the semaphore need to obtain it already initialized. Otherwise the initialization of the semaphore itself is subject to race conditions.

Comment: Are you required to use SysV semaphores for some reason?

Comment: That's what I was taught during the course, but I guess there won't be a problem with alternative approach. Why, are they outdated or something?

Comment: [POSIX semaphores](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview) and [shared memory](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open) are the more modern and somewhat better-designed API.  However, it's not clear to me whether they have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like the following:

1. Call `semget(key, nsems, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL)`. If this succeeds you have now created a new semaphore set, which you should then set via `semctl()`
2. If previous `semget()` failed, call `semget()` again, without the `IPC_EXCL` flag.

I'd also recommend using a lockfile (via `flock()` or similar) to ensure that the semaphore set isn't used until it is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

i think all the users of the semaphore need to obtain it already initialized. Otherwise the initialization of the semaphore itself is subject to race conditions. 
you can have a daemon which initialize the semaphore at system bootstrap and take care of

```
create_sem;
raise_sem;
```

while clients just execute

```
get_sem_handle;
```

Comment: So, the only option is to have an entirely separate process that would initialize the semaphores? And I'd have to run it each time before starting a client (because I can't really tinker with init scripts on uni computers)? Hm, wish there was something more elegant...